Evaluating "extended" Hurwitz zeta $\zeta(2,a)$
I want to evaluate the following sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^2}
\end{equation}
Which is similar to $\zeta(2,a)$, but it ranges over the entire line and it's alternating. I know you can just note that this is minus the residue of $f(z)=\pi\csc\pi z$ at $z = −a$, such that:
\begin{equation}
\pi \frac{d}{dz} \csc(\pi z) \bigg|_{z = -a} = -\frac{\pi^2 \cos(-\pi a)}{\sin^2(-\pi a)}=-S
\end{equation}
Yielding the result. That's fine and all, but I've been wanting a different approach. I've tried using the weierstrass factorization for trig functions, but got nowhere. If anyone can hint me to some approach, or give me a resolution without contour integration or residue theorem, I'll be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Does the simplification $$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^2}\=\frac{1}{4} \left(-\zeta\left(2,\frac{1-a}{2}\right)+\zeta\left(2,\frac{a}{2}\right)-\zeta\left(2,\frac{a+1}{2}\right)+\zeta\left(2,1-\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)=\pi^2 \cot(\pi a) \csc(\pi a)$$ given by Mathematica qualify as a different approach?

how can i prove this identity though?

Cross-posted to Math Overflow.

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^2}=\frac12 F\left(\frac a2\right)-F(a),\qquad F(a)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(n+a)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi a}
$$
where the last equality (is well-known and) can be obtained from the infinite product expansion of the sine function (by taking the second derivative of its logarithm).

Sorry, I don't see how the first equality holds.

@JohannWagner: it's like $\sum(-1)^n a_n=2\sum a_{2n}-\sum a_n$.

Making the problem more general, consider
$$S_a(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{t^n}{(n+a)^2}$$Integrate with respect to $a$
$$I_a(t)=\int S_a(t)\,da=-\int\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n+a}=\frac 1t \Phi \left(\frac{1}{t},1,1-a\right)-\Phi (t,1,a)$$
Differentiate with respect to $a$
$$S_a(t)=\frac 1t \Phi \left(\frac{1}{t},2,1-a\right)+\Phi (t,2,a)$$ Let $t=-1$ and use
$$\Phi \left(-1,2,1-a\right)=\frac 14 \Bigg(\zeta\left(2,\frac{1-a}{2}\right)-\zeta\left(2,\frac{2-a}{2}\right)   \Bigg)$$
$$\Phi (-1,2,a)=\frac 14 \Bigg(\zeta \left(2,\frac{a}{2}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,\frac{a+1}{2}\right)  \Bigg)$$
Recombining
$$S_a(-1)=\frac 14 \Bigg(\zeta \left(2,\frac{2-a}{2}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{1-a}{2}\right) +\zeta \left(2,\frac{a}{2}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{1+a}{2}\right) \Bigg)$$
$$S_a(-1)=\frac 14 \Bigg(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2-a}{2}\right)- \psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) +\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right) \Bigg)$$
$$\large S_a(-1)=\pi ^2 \cot (\pi  a) \csc (\pi  a)$$
